# Is it possible to use beaglebone (black) analog pins as GPIOs?

Tags: beagleboneblack, gpio

Analog pins of arduino boards can be used as GPIO but is it also possible for the beaglebone boards ? Especially the black model.

And if it is possible, how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to e.g. the [BBB SRM (System Reference Manual)](https://github.com/beagleboard/beaglebone-black/wiki/System-Reference-Manual#712_Connector_P9), specifically: 
 **7.1.2 Connector P9** or "Table 13. Expansion Header P9 Pinout" in the PDF version.

tl;dr: **no**

Please also note that those pins only tolerate up to 1.8V. Applying any higher voltage will destroy the ADC and possibly affect the whole chip.